# "Quelques fois" for "a few times"?

Tags: traduction, adverbes

"I've watched this film a few times."

> J'ai regardé ce film quelques fois.

Is the use of *quelques fois* correct here? If this sentence is spoken, would *quelques fois* get confused with *quelquefois* that means "sometimes" (*parfois* / *des fois*)? Are there any other alternatives for translating "a few times"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can mean "a few times", but you're right that there is some ambiguity (though less in the passé than in the présent).

Some other options are *plusieurs fois*, *à quelques/plusieurs reprises* (same quantifier but with this noun no confusion is possible), *en quelques occasions* (same deal) ...

Comment: Thanks. I thought about *plusieurs fois* as well, but I think "a few times" could mean 2-3 times where as *plusieurs fois* (=several times) would usually be more than that.

Comment: Fair enough -- though that impression might be [contestable](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9hu3UcCZwZ44.html) :)

Answer (score 1):

That sentence doesn't quite feel right, although it is probably grammatically correct. That *quelque fois* at the end of the sentence is probably what doesn't work for me. I would say:

> J'ai regardé ce film *plusieurs* fois.

Note that *plusieurs* could be as few as 2 or 3 times. It does not necessarily imply *many* times.

Probably only in familiar spoken language, for more than 2 or 3 times, you could say:

> J'ai vu ce film *plein de* fois.

For only 2 or 3 times, you could also simply say:

> J'ai vu ce film *deux ou trois* fois.